# Why do I get the message "program not found" when running "mal" for Latex

Tags: latex

just started using Ubuntu (11.10 oneiric). It is running on a virtual machine.
I used to use SuSE. However, SuSE is now with Novel, which goes hand in hand with Microsoft. So now shifted to Ubuntu.

For documentation I use LaTeX and installed a package. This package uses a pre-processer (it is called "mal").

I ran the textconfig rehash command as required, but when I try to run the program, I get a "program not found" error. I am guessing that it is not in my path. (a sudo did not help)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you mean `texconfig`. To use it you must install the [texlive-binaries](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/texlive-binaries) [image: Install texlive-binaries] package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries
```

or clicking here:

[image: Install via the software center]